# sending email are failing because rate limit exceeded , how to overcome this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Ours is spring boot app , we are sending emails to our vendors by making calls to exchange server , but at some point we receiving to many requests and we are sending so many emails that , email server is throwing error like rate limit exceeded and connection reset , connection closed ,

can anyone suggest how to overcome this issue ? we do not have control on email server , we are just using email server .

how to send emails at slow phase even we received so many requests from our clients ?

Comment: I think you need to implement some queue mechanism. For example Kafka. Collect all mail requests to kafka topic, and process it via scheduled job.

Comment: No need to drag in a massive hammer (Kafka) to crack a tiny problem like this. Hand off your email tasks to a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with one thread backed by a  `DelayQueue`. All you have to do is calculate the optimum delay for each item added such that you won't exceed your rate limit.

Comment: @AndyBrown , can you please provide details on this ? and also one doubt , if application restarts in between and if we use ThreadPoolExecutor , then all pending requests will be lost , am i correct , then that is big problem am i correct ?

Comment: Yes if the app restarts and your requests are not serialized then you will lose any in the queue. If this is important to you then you can always back your queue with persistent storage (e.g. a database or just files on disk). It's extra work but likely to be less total cost than telling your production support team that they've now got to support a big third party messaging system that got brought in as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decouple the email sending function. Put them in something like Kafka and then the Kafka consumer can ratelimit them.